# Trouble identifying difference in BeautifulSoup commented tables

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm aware of some other questions regarding commented HTML tables from this site but I don't believe they answer this specific question.

I am trying to scrape [this page](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html) for all the tables with in it.  I can get all but one of them, "Shooting".

I recognize that all but "Per Game" are commented out in the page source.  In order to handle commented out tables, I'm using code that looks like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
comment_table = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and stat in x)
soup = BeautifulSoup(comment_table, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", id=stat)
```

`stat` can be any number of "stats".  Ones that work are things like "per_minute", "pbp", "adj_shooting", etc.

It first finds the commented out tables and then proceeds to parse the table as normal from there.  With all the commented tables, `table` is a table Tag.  When `stat` is "shooting", however, `table` is empty.

When looking for instances containing "shooting", the `comment_table` line is returning the text `'Player shooting history'` instead of the expected table.  I've verified that there is "shooting" in the commented out text (in the page source).

Can someone help me figure out what's different about this table?

Comment: have you checked that it´s not js created content? I scraped this page a few month ago and ran into some similar issues.

Comment: I can't imagine this one single table would be but how would I check that?  It's in the page source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is matching on an earlier instance where that string is present. As you are looking for it within an id I think you can alter the following line:

```
comment_table = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and stat in x)
```

to

```
comment_table = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and f'id="{stat}' in x)
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from bs4 import NavigableString
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html')
soup = bs(res.text, "lxml")
stat = 'shooting'
comment_table = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and f'id="{stat}' in x)
soup = bs(comment_table, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", id=stat)
print(table)
```

You could do variations on a theme with regex for example. The idea is to ensure you are looking in the id attribute for that value.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried this and `...and "id=shooting"...` but it found nothing.

Comment: Seems to work for me in my example. Not tested for your others.

Comment: oh I got your code to work.  What's with the single double-quote in the f-string?  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: that is because the attribute should be id="<some id>"  and I simply closed off early before second "

Comment: No worries. Hopefully that continues to work for your others.